# How to check if an ec2 instance is running or not with an if statement?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto3

I have an instance-id of an ec2 instance. How to check if that ec2 instance is running or not using an if statement? I am using Python and Boto3.

Comment: this should help `https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_status`

Comment: do you have any code you can share?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using the boto3 Resource method:

```py
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

instance = ec2_resource.Instance('i-12345')
if instance.state['Name'] == 'running':
    print('It is running')
```

Using the boto3 Client method:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

response = ec2_client.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=['i-12345'])
if response['InstanceStatuses'][0]['InstanceState']['Name'] == 'running':
    print('It is running')
```

Answer (score 8):

I think that important thing is that by default, only running instances are described. So if you want to check the state of instance that not necessary is running, than you need to specify "IncludeAllInstances" option. So it should looks like this:

```
response = ec2_client.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=['i-12345'], IncludeAllInstances=True)
if response['InstanceStatuses'][0]['InstanceState']['Name'] == 'running':
    print('It is running')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
response = ec2_client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
if "".join([ "Running" if x['State']['Name'] == "running" else "Stopped" for r in response['Reservations'] for x in r['Instances']]) == "Running":
    print("Instances is running")
else:
    print("Instances is not running")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).